# Uniform convergence after transforming?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I face a problem now, it is known that $f_n(x)$ converge to $+\infty$ pointwise as $n\rightarrow+\infty$, but I want to prove $f_n(x)$ converge to $+\infty$ uniformly.

I can prove $\arctan f_n(x)$ converges to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ uniformly. Does this imply that $f_n(x)$ converge to $+\infty$ uniformly?

Comment: You need two variables to talk about uniform convergence. As it stands it is difficult to understand what you are saying. And how is probability involved here?

Comment: Sorry, I edit my problem again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does, because $\tan$ is a bijective and increasing mapping from $[0, \frac \pi 2)$ to $[0, \infty) $.

More detailed: Given $M > 0$ we have that $0 < \arctan M < \frac \pi 2$. The uniform convergence of $\arctan f_n(x) \to  \frac \pi 2$ implies the existence of an $n_0 \in \Bbb N$ such that
$$
 \arctan f_n(x) > \arctan M \text{ for all $n \ge n_0$ and all $x$.}
$$
It follows that
$$
 f_n(x) > M  \text{ for all $n \ge n_0$ and all $x$.}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume we have a sequence of functions $f_n(x)$ defined on some set $D\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $\arctan f_n(x) \to \pi/2$ uniformly on $D$. We prove that $f_n $ converge to $+\infty$ uniformly, i.e. 
$$
\forall A > 0 \ \ \exists N = N(A) \in \mathbb{N} \ \ \ \text{such that if } \ \ n>N \ \ \text{ then } \  f_n(x) > A \ \ \forall x \in D.
$$
Assume for contradiction, that the above does not hold, that is 
$$
\tag{1} \exists A > 0 \ \ \text{s.t.} \ \  \forall N \in \mathbb{N} \ \ \exists x_N \in D \ \ \text{s.t.} \ \ f_N(x_N) \leq A .
$$

In view of uniform convergence of $\arctan f_n$ we have that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is $N = N(\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ such that whenever $n> N$ then $|\arctan f_n(x) - \pi/2| < \varepsilon$ for all $x\in D$ . Combining this with $(1)$ and using the fact that $\arctan$ is increasing, from $(1)$ we get 
$$
\pi/2 - \varepsilon < \arctan f_n(x_n) \leq \arctan A < \pi/2 \tag{2}
$$
if $n>N(\varepsilon)$.
Since $A>0$ is fixed, we can choose $\varepsilon> 0$ small enough to make the inequality $(2)$ false. This contradiction proves uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $\pi/2$ on $D$.